# Tkinter: set StringVar after <Key> event, including the key pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget

Every time a character is entered into a `Text` widget, I want to get the contents of that widget and subtract its length from a certain number (basically a "you have x characters left" deal).

But the `StringVar()` is always one event behind. This is, from what I gather, because the event is processed before the character is entered into the Text widget. This means that if I have 3 characters in the field and I enter a 4th, the `StringVar` is updated but is still 3 characters long, then it updates to 4 when I enter a 5th character.

Is there a way to keep the two in line?

Here's some code. I removed irrelevant parts.

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.char_count = StringVar()
    self.char_count.set("140 chars left")

    self.post_tweet = Text(self.master)
    self.post_tweet.bind("<Key>", self.count)
    self.post_tweet.grid(...)

    self.char_count = Label(self.master, textvariable=self.foo)
    self.char_count.grid(...)

def count(self):
    self.x = len(self.post_tweet.get(1.0, END))
    self.char_count.set(str(140 - self.x))
```

Comment: Can you post some code? It's hard to understand what you want and what you've tried without seeing anything.

Comment: No, the `StringVar` isn't one event behind. The problem is that the default handler for the `<Key>` event—the one that updates the variable—runs _after_ your handler, instead of before. You can see this is you just check the variable from any other event after your `<Key>` event.

Comment: I think you might have another problem here. IIRC, a default `Text` widget has an implicit newline at the end. So, when you do that `self.post_tweet.get(1.0, END))`, don't you also get one character too many?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to add a new bindtag after the class binding. That way the class binding will fire before your binding. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513906/7432) to the question [How to bind self events in Tkinter Text widget after it will binded by Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3501849/7432) for an example. That answer uses an entry widget rather than a text widget, but the concept of bindtags is identical between those two widgets. Just be sure to use `Text` rather than `Entry` where appropriate.

Another solution is to bind on KeyRelease, since the default bindings happen on KeyPress.

Here's an example showing how to do it with bindtags:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.post_tweet = tk.Text(self)
        bindtags = list(self.post_tweet.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(2, "custom") # index 1 is where most default bindings live
        self.post_tweet.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))

        self.post_tweet.bind_class("custom", "<Key>", self.count)
        self.post_tweet.grid()

        self.char_count = tk.Label(self)
        self.char_count.grid()

    def count(self, event):
        current = len(self.post_tweet.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
        remaining = 140-current
        self.char_count.configure(text="%s characters remaining" % remaining)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Alright, it worked fine for me. Mostly. I discovered that the default widget name was something to the tune of ".4456585", rather than what I named the instance of the widget. Still all worked fine, but when I ran `len(self.text.get(1.0, END)`, it was 1 bigger than expected. So 'hello' would be 6 characters long rather than 5. I solved this by just subtracting 1 and all is fine, but I'm curious about why this happens in the first place.

Comment: @RoryByrne: the text widget always adds an extra newline, to guarantee there's always at least one newline. It seems odd, but it really does make a lot of things simpler. Whenever you pull text from the widget you should use `"end-1c"`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for all the help both. @abarnert

Answer (score 3):

Like most events in Tk, your `<Key>` handler is fired *before* the event is processed by the built-in bindings, rather than after. This allows you to, for example, prevent the normal processing from happening, or change what it does.

But this means that you can't access the new value (whether via a `StringVar`, or just by calling `entry.get()`), because it hasn't been updated yet.

---

If you're using `Text`, there's a virtual event `<<Modified>>` that gets fired after the "modified" flag changes. Assuming you weren't using that flag for another purpose (e.g., in a text editor, you might want to use it to mean "enable the Save button"), you can use it to do exactly what you want:

```
def count(self, event=None):
    if not self.post_tweet.edit_modified():
        return
    self.post_tweet.edit_modified(False)
    self.x = len(self.post_tweet.get(1.0, END))
    self.char_count.set(str(140 - self.x))

# ...

self.post_tweet.bind("<<Modified>>", self.count)
```

---

Usually, when you want something like this, you want an `Entry` rather than a `Text`. Which provides a much nicer way to do this: validation. As with everything beyond the basics in Tkinter, there's no way you're going to figure this out without reading the Tcl/Tk docs (which is why the Tkinter docs link to them). And really, even the Tk docs don't describe validation very well. But here's how it works:

```
def count(self, new_text):
    self.x = len(new_text)
    self.char_count.set(str(140 - self.x))
    return True

# ...

self.vcmd = self.master.register(self.count)
self.post_tweet = Edit(self.master, validate='key',
                       validatecommand=(self.vcmd, '%P'))
```

The `validatecommand` can take a list of 0 or more arguments to pass to the function. The `%P` argument gets the new value the entry will have if you allow it. See [`VALIDATION`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16) in the Entry manpage for more details.

If you want the entry to be rejected (e.g., if you want to actually block someone from entering more than 140 characters), just return `False` instead of `True`.

---

By the way, it's worth looking over the [Tk wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk) and searching for Tkinter recipes on [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/). It's a good bet someone's got wrappers around `Text` and `Entry` that hide all the extra stuff you have to do to make these solutions (or others) work so you just have to write the appropriate `count` method. There *might* even be a `Text` wrapper that adds `Entry`-style validation.

There are a few other ways you could do this, but they all have downsides.

Add a `trace` to hook all writes to a `StringVar` attached to your widget. This will get fired by *any* writes to the variable. I guarantee that you will get the infinite-recursive-loop problem the first time you try to use it for validation, and then you'll run into other more subtle problems in the future. The usual solution is to create a sentinel flag, which you check every time you come into the handler to make sure you're not doing it recursively, and then set while you're doing anything that can trigger a recursive event. (That wasn't necessary for the `edit_modified` example above because we could just ignore anyone setting the flag to `False`, and we only set it to `False`, so there's no danger of infinite recursion.)

You can get the new char (or multi-char string) out of the `<Key>` virtual event. But then, what do you do with it? You need to know where it's going to be added, which character(s) it's going to be overwriting, etc. If you don't do all the work to simulate `Entry`—or, worse, `Text`—editing yourself, this is no better than just doing `len(entry.get()) + 1`.

Comment: While I don't understand quite how validation works, it does the trick here _if_ I use an Entry widget. The problem is that I'm using a Text widget (and I can't use an Entry widget instead), and so I get "TclError: unknown option '-validatecommand'". Is there a way to get validation to work with the Text widget?

I can try look into your other suggestions but I don't want to get in over my head.

Comment: This solution can't work for the text widget, as it doesn't support the validation options.

Comment: Sorry, without seeing your code, I assumed you were looking for a very short string, which is an obvious case for `Entry`. For entering tweets, yeah, you want `Text`, and there's no validation there. It's possible that the [Tk wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk) has a way to apply `Entry`-validation to `Text`, but otherwise… let me think about it and write up something appropriate.