# How to run tkinter code after event?

Tags: python, tkinter

For example if I press a key within `Text` widget a letter is inserted. If I bind some code to `<Key>` or `<KeyRelease>` in `Text` widget, it is run before text is inserted. But I want to manipulate the text that was inserted (highlight it for example). For that I need to run my code after tkinter runs its default code. How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771749/tkinter-set-stringvar-after-key-event-including-the-key-pressed?rq=1 ?