# tkinter Entry updates once only via StringVar and only with manual key press afterwards

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an Entry that updates once via a textvariable set to a StringVar, but then only via manual keypress from user after that.

I'm writing a GUI using model-view-controller pattern.

I have a controller class, that owns the main tk object. 
It also owns a StringVar(). I've set up a callback to fire when the StringVar is written to.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.fname = StringVar()
        self.fname.trace('w', self.file_name_updated)
        self.view = View(self.root, self.fname)

    def file_name_updated(self, name, index, mode):
        varValue = self.root.globalgetvar(name)
        print ('filename updated!!! %s' % varValue)
        self.root.globalsetvar(name, 'changing it again!')

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

class View:
    def __init__(self, tk, fname_var):
        self.form = tk
        self.fileNameVar = fname_var

        self.inFileTxt = Entry(self.form, textvariable=fname_var)
        self.inFileTxt.grid(row=1)

        self.inFileBtn = Button(self.form, text="Browse ...", command=self.open_file)
        self.inFileBtn.grid(row=1, column=8)

    def open_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename()
        self.fileNameVar.set(fname) # update the updateable text 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Controller()
    c.run()
```

The controller creates a View instance. The View object, draws an Entry box which assigns the StringVar to its `textvariable` attribute.
The View object also has a `Button`. When clicked, this sets the value of the StringVar(), and fires the callback.

So far so good. The `StringVar` has been set to the chosen filename, the callback fires, I see my debug. But then, in my callback, I update the value of the `StringVar` again. It's just a test, ultimately I want to clear the value of the `StringVar` if the filename chosen has errors (but that wasn't working, so I'm trying to narrow it down).

Anyway, I'm expecting the text in the entry box to say 'changing it again!'. But I don't see that. It stays the same.

Debug shows that the value of the variable is 'changing it again!', but the Entry box has not updated.

However, when I place the cursor inside the Entry box and press SPACE, then my text gets updated.

How can I update the text without user having to enter anything?

possibly related - event processing, StringVar is always 1 event behind. 
[Tkinter: set StringVar after <Key> event, including the key pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771749/tkinter-set-stringvar-after-key-event-including-the-key-pressed?rq=1)

Comment: When I select a file, the `StringVar()` becomes the file name, when I try and change the filename the `StringVar()` changes to "changing it again!", I don't see an error?

Comment: Really? Hmm. Must be something else in my code then. The entire thing is too big to paste here unfortunately.

Comment: You can always try using `.update()` or `.update_idletasks()`, this isn't the best solution but it sometimes works

Comment: I tried `update_idletasks()` with no joy, but I will try `update()`.

Comment: If that doesn't work all I can suggest is having a debug at every place you change the `StringVar()`

Comment: Ok - I'll try that. Even the cut down version doesn't work for me.

Comment: This "cut down" version is not nrunnable as-is, so the problem is likely in the code you aren't showing us. Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BryanOakley - updated.

Comment: @TomFuller: neither `update` nor `update_idletasks` should have any effect here.

Answer (score 0):

When the `insert` method of the `Entry` is used instead of the `set` method of the `StringVar` in the `open_file` function, it works as expected (the text is replaced by "changing it again!"):

```
def open_file(self):
    fname = askopenfilename()
    self.inFileTxt.delete(0, 'end')
    self.inFileTxt.insert(0, fname)
```

instead of

```
def open_file(self):
    fname = askopenfilename()
    self.fileNameVar.set(fname) # update the updateable text
```

But I don't understand why because in both cases `file_name_updated` is executed. So if someone can explain this, please edit this answer.